# How to create more than 1 check box in ListView object?

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox, subitem

I am using a `ListWiew` which has checked property selected so it have a check box on every item in first column. Now, I want to have another check box on second column also, but can't find anything useful in the properties of my list view to have more than 1 check box.

How would I do this?

Comment: ListView doesn't support that.  Any grid control will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use a DataGrid? It can show as much checkboxes as needed and in any place :)

```
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

            string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk);
            chk.HeaderText = "Check Data";
            chk.Name = "chk";
            dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[3].Value = true;
```

Comment: This might take me some time to switch from ListView to data grid, but this might be worth it.